# How to Remove Last Added View Controller From Container

Tags: ios

How to Remove Last Added View Controller From Container

I have used this code to remove last added view container

```
 UIViewController *vc = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController];

[self.ctr addSubview:news.view];
```

Comment: are you using navigation stack...???

Comment: i have a container and two view contollers . not using navigation

Comment: Okay try with this,,, add it `[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];` before this line `[vc.view removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Call Method willMoveToParentViewController:nil

Then Call Remove From Super View

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; 

[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
```